Flutter: Unable to create MSALPublicClientApplication
I am using the msal_auth library to log in.
First of all, I am trying the example app to test on ios.
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:msal_auth/msal_auth.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await dotenv.load(fileName: "assets/.env");
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _clientId = dotenv.env['MS_CLIENT_ID'];
  final _tenantId = dotenv.env['MS_TENANT_ID'];
  late final _authority =
      'https://login.microsoftonline.com/$_tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize';
  final _scopes = <String>[
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('MSAL example app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: getToken,
                child: const Text('Get Token'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: getTokenSilently,
                child: const Text('Get Token silent'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 24),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: logout,
                child: const Text('Logout'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<MsalAuth> getMsalAuth() async {
    return MsalAuth.createPublicClientApplication(
      clientId: _clientId!,
      scopes: _scopes,
      androidConfig: AndroidConfig(
        configFilePath: 'assets/msal_config.json',
        tenantId: _tenantId,
      ),
      iosConfig: IosConfig(authority: _authority),
    );
  }

  Future<void> getToken() async {
    try {
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      final user = await msalAuth.acquireToken();
      log('User data: ${user?.toJson()}');
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> getTokenSilently() async {
    try {
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      final user = await msalAuth.acquireTokenSilent();
      log('User data: ${user?.toJson()}');
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    try {
      final msalAuth = await getMsalAuth();
      await msalAuth.logout();
    } on MsalException catch (e) {
      log('Msal exception with error: ${e.errorMessage}');
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

I am getting this error on all 3 buttons
[log] Msal exception with error: Unable to create MSALPublicClientApplication
This is my info.plist
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>     
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>{app_bundle_id}</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>msauth.{app_bundle_id}</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>msauthv2</string>
      <string>msauthv3</string>
    </array>

I have tried hardcoded Client Id and Tenant Id too but I am getting same error. I am using the Flutter 3.24.4 and msal:2.1.0
I have also added keychain sharing in XCode signin and capabilities.
